# Google Calendar API and Coldfusion

Tags: api, coldfusion, google-calendar-api

I started doing research on integrating a Google Calendar into one of my projects that is written using Coldfusion. I realized that it seems that Google does not support (I don't think that's the correct word) Coldfusion in their library downloads. I did a quick Google search and did come across a project someone did to get it to work, although this is only to read a calendar. I want to be able to add/edit/view events.

Is there any suggestions on how I could get this to work? I thought of a stupid possibility of attempting to include a PHP page inside a .cfm file but that obviously didn't work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I am not currently sure how to get this to work.

Comment: [It's a REST API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/) - all you need is [cfhttp](http://cfdocs.org/cfhttp).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ray Camden has already done all of the work for you and hosted his project on RIA Forge

http://googlecal.riaforge.org/

Comment: I would like to say thank you, I guess when I was searching google I found an older version. This saved me a lot of time!

Comment: The above link is not working. Do you have any other link?

Comment: @Arun try https://github.com/billeatman/CF-GoogleCal-V3